# What size should the play store icon by for Android with XF?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Also does anyone have any suggestions on how to create this and can you confirm if I need to give it rounded corners. Ideally I am looking to see if there's an online way to create this from an image I supply or with Illustrator.  So far I found app icon.co site but that doesn't seem to generate what I am looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to give it rounded corners. The you should use `Adaptive icons`. Everything is very well documented in the official [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive).

Basically, you will have 2 layers - background & foreground. The OS will take care of the rest.

I don't know if there is a website that can provide you with everything needed (like foreground & background images together). I am using [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html). It comes close enough and has a lot of configurations and is open-sourced ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/romannurik/AndroidAssetStudio)).

P.S. Also a good read is the official [Google Play icon guide](https://developer.android.com/google-play/resources/icon-design-specifications).

Comment: Android Asset Studio looks very good for my needs.  Do you also have a play store_icon.png in the location where I have?  I am wondering what that is for.

Comment: If it's 512x512, then it should be indeed the Play store icon. Look at the last link in my answer. This should be uploaded to Google Play console, when a build will be uploaded there for distribution.